# Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor

Tags: r

Working on my first ever plot in R. I figured out how to make a barplot like this:

```
ggplot(output, aes(x=X1, y=X2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
+     labs(x="Population", y="Values")
```

I want to reorder the x-axis, so I found this command:

```
output <- factor(output, levels=c("B", "A", "C"))
```

This gives me the error: 
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is output a data-frame? Perhaps change output to output$X1 can solve this issue.

Comment: That does it, I just have to change both instances of output to output$X1. Could you add that as an answer so I can give you credit? Maybe with an explanation as to what the $ does or how it keeps my data as a data-frame?

Comment: I am glad the issue is solved. As long as people can see the comments and get information they need, there is no need to submit an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can convert vector in the data frame and then put in ggplot1.

Step 1: Make DataFrame

```
outmatrix <- matrix(output, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
outdf <- as.data.frame(m1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Step 2: create ggplot by aes x as column name.

```
ggplot(outdf, aes(x = outdf$V1)) +
geom_bar() +
xlab("Pclass") +
ylab("Total Count")
```